# Merge replication add new tables

Tags: sql-server, replication

I have setup merge replication in SQL Server 2012 for a database with around 300 tables and two subscribers. Whenever I add a new table in the publication properties, the agent generates a snapshot for the all the tables again. 
How can I configure it to only create snapshot of the newly added articles and only synchronise those ones to subscribers?

Answer (score -2):

To avoid generating a full snapshot when you add a new article, publication properties @immediate_sync and @allow_anonymous must be set to 0.

It's likely @immediate_sync is 1 (true) in your configuration, so snapshot agent creates a full snapshot.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188738.aspx

Comment: Hi, I think that's applicable for transactional and snapshot replication. Merge replication does not have a property called @immediate_sync

Comment: Sorry, yes, you're right. For merge replication, there is no such option and you have to generate a new full snapshot. However, only new articles should be sent to subscriber.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7f54ea68-216a-4957-a277-4cf4daf50e6f/add-article-to-merge-replication-without-having-to-set-forceinvalidatesnapshot-1?forum=sqlreplication